# Matrix multiplication on a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have the following dataframe

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = [[30, 19, 6], [12, 23, 14], [8, 18, 20]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data = data, index = ['A', 'B', 'C'], columns = ['Bulgary', 'Robbery', 'Car Theft'])
df['r_Total'] = df.iloc[:, :3].sum(axis=1)
df.loc['c_Total'] = df.iloc[:3, :].sum(axis=0)
df
```

|  | Bulgary | Robbery | Car Theft | r_Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 30 | 19 | 6 | 55 |
| B | 12 | 23 | 14 | 49 |
| C | 8 | 18 | 20 | 46 |
| c_Total | 50 | 60 | 40 | 150 |

Now, I want to obtain expectation matrix `E`, where

```
E_{ij} = (ith_r_Total/Total)(jth_c_Total/Total)*Total
```

(eg: E_{00} = (55/150)*(50/150)*150.) How should I accomplish this?

Of course, there's always a brute force method to iterate over i and j in two for-loops, but is there a smarter way of doing it?

Mathematically, `r_Total * c_Total / 150` would give me the answer I want. It really boils down to how to do matrix multiplication on dataframe. I tried:

```
df['r_Total'].dot(df.loc['c_Total'])
```

But got the following error:

```
ValueError: matrices are not aligned
```

I also tried:

```
df['r_Total'].mul(df.loc['c_Total'])
```

But got

```
A                NaN
B                NaN
Bulgary          NaN
C                NaN
Car Theft        NaN
Robbery          NaN
Total        22500.0
Name: Total, dtype: float64
```

But this is not my expected output. It is 1 col x 1 row, so my expected output should be a 3x3 matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To perform a matrix multiplication, the dimensions have to match. Since your expected output is of shape (3, 3), yet the two "matrices" are columns and rows, you'll have to make them matrices of shape (3, 1) and (1, 3) so that the multiplication would have the desired shape. You can do that by using double brackets (`[[]]`) when selecting.

To make the multiplication work, you'll have to convert at least one of the dataframes into a numpy array (that's what's happening with `.values`)

Also, to exclude the "_Total" rows, only select up to the last element.

Then divide by the last element in the dataframe which is 150 in your example.

```py
res = df.loc[df.index[:-1], ['c_Total']].dot(df.loc[['r_Total']].values[:, :-1]).div(df.iat[-1,-1])
```

[image: res]

Comment: In order to perform matrix multiplication for arbitrary dataframe M,N, do I always need to convert one to numpy datatype?

Comment: imo the code is much more intuitive/clean if you do it all via numpy: `res = df['r_Total'][:, None] * df.loc['c_Total'][None, :] / df.iloc[-1, -1]`

Comment: then you can put it back into a dataframe: `out = pd.DataFrame(res, index=df.index, columns=df.columns)`

Comment: @JamesC dataframes have labels (index/columns) so if they don't match, even if the dimensions match, you get a dataframe of NaNs but of the correct dimension when you do matrix operations on them. So if the labels don't match, you'll have to convert at least one of them into a numpy array (arrays don't have labels, so any operation using them will work as long as the dimensions match).

Comment: Thanks! I used ```DataFrame.to_numpy()``` to convert to matrix and everything resolved easily.

Comment: Just wondering, is it a common practice to 1. convert dataframe to numpy, 2. do some operation, and 3. convert the result back to dataframe?

Comment: @tdy I thought of it but I felt like pandas way is more terse and would require shorter explanation. Numpy would require transpose etc. Btw, `df['r_Total'][:, None]` conversion is deprecated.